# python treeview cell/row borders

Tags: python, treeview, styles, border

I have a python tk treeview for listing items, what I couldn't find is a way to stilysh a bit the whole list. i've done a massive google search but didn't find a way to add vertical line borders between each item, maybe it's not possible? I don't like the alternate-line-colors style. I tried tag_configure method but as far as i know it only allows font/foreground/background options.

thank you in advance

Comment: I am also seeking an answer to this question

Comment: check out this page, someone tried to work it out http://wiki.tcl.tk/26993 but not sure if it has been coded yet